# Plant with orange-red leaves and white-purplish flowers, can anyone help me identify it?

Tags: identification, annuals

I bought this at an unmanned roadside stall, and there was no name. It was just four or five bright orange leaves big at that time in early May. It has now grown to be at least 75cm high and wide and the leaves are turning a darker red (though there is still some orange present). I think it's an annual plant that won't survive the winter (at least not in the Dutch climate) as the rest of the stall was filled with things like petunia, fuchsia, and lobelia, which also don't survive winters here.

I really like it and would like to be able to buy one next year, even if that same roadside shop doesn't offer one. So what is this called?

[image: A picture showing the orange-red leaves and flowers]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**It is coleus**! 
The shape of leaves, colour and the flower stick confirms it's a coleus.

There's a lot of varieties of coleus of different colours and shape. This may be **Big Red Judy** or **Color Blaze Sedona Sunset** or something other that I don't know.

You can help the plant survive winters, take them indoors. [This](https://www.gardeningknowhow.com/ornamental/foliage/coleus/overwintering-coleus.htm) or [this article](https://www.farmersalmanac.com/winter-annual-plants-indoors-69474) can help you or just google it.

Comment: Wow, this is barely recognizable from the common older varieties. Go plant breeders!

Comment: @kevinskio some colour, right?

Comment: I don't have any coleus any more, but I seem to remember them going very leggy if left to flower.  That was growing them as houseplants though; outdoors they'll get more light and it might not be as bad

Comment: @ChrisH I dunno what is considered leggy for a plant, but [this is the whole thing](https://imgur.com/a/db7F7yA). It has taken over pretty much the entire pot, I didn't realize it would get that big. I'm definitely going to try and get some seeds and cuttings to propagate over winter, so I'll hopefully have something to plant in the middle of the pot(s) (instead of on the side) next year :)

Comment: @Tinkeringbell I mean lots of stem and not much else, at least in subsequent growth. But if it's not going to be brought indoors for winter, that won't matter. I've grown coleus varieties from seed, never tried cuttings.

Comment: @Tinkeringbell You will know when it's getting leggy. Without any flower stick it will have long stems without leaves or small leaves too apart from each other. This will happen if it doesn't get enough light. What you have is normal and healthy plant with those flower stick. The ones that I have is even bigger than yours.

Comment: @Tinkeringbell I have propagated them from cuttings, not seeds and it is quite annoying(I mean sooo easy) to propagate from cuttings. It will produce roots even from the smallest part, from a leaf alone and whatnot. You can go with hydroponic methods also to produce roots. I have placed it in my garden soil. Sometimes I think it to be a weed in my garden, tends to take up all the space.

Comment: @Spectra I've read about how easy they grow roots, yes. Biggest hurdle here will probably be getting them enough light through the winter. Last winter my houseplants basically withered away because my living room has north facing windows and some sort of roof outside blocking even more light... can't put them in the bedroom as that gets too cold, and I refuse to buy special lamps and waste a bunch of energy XD

Comment: @Tinkeringbell Wow, saving energy is cool! Let's hope for the best. Don't forget to comment here at the end of winter, we would love to see it again :D